# search multiple pattern in file and delete line if pattern matches

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sed, awk

For ex, a file contain contents:

```
10.45.56.84 raj
10.49.31.81 mum
10.49.31.86 mum
10.81.51.92 guj
10.45.56.116 raj
10.45.56.84 raj
```

I want to search `10.45.56.84` and `10.81.51.92` in the above file and delete line if pattern matches.

Also i want to do this in single command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another solution:

```
 awk '!/10.45.56.84|10.81.51.92/' file
```

Comment: This will also remove the line: `10145x56y84`.  Probably acceptable for the given input, but `awk '!/10\.45\.56\.84|10\.81\.51\.92/'` would be more accurate.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
sed -e '/10[.]45[.]56[.]84/d;/10[.]81[.]51[.]92/d' file
```

This has two sed "d"  delete commands separated by a semicolon. However, they are only executed if they match the respective pattern enclosed between slashes that come before eachcommand.

You can also use grep:

```
grep -Ev '10[.]45[.]56[.]84|10[.]81[.]51[.]92' file
```

The "-v" flag tell grep to print only the lines that don't match the pattern, and we use the OR operator "|" to match either pattern. The "-E" flag is used so we don't have to escape the OR operator with a backslash.

In both cases we place the period between brackets because otherwise the period is used as an operator that matches any character. You may place more characters inside a single pair of brackets, and they will be interpreted as to match one of the characters specified.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: In the `sed` command there is no need to execute second comparison if the first one succeed. It works (and **+1** for that) but you could start next cycle just there using `b` instruction: `sed -e '/10[.]45[.]56[.]84/ { d; b }; /10[.]81[.]51[.]92/d'`

Comment: The "d" command actually starts the next cycle. This is also something that can have unexpected behavior. The"D" command behaves the same way, but deletes only up to the first newline character, restarting the cycle but only loading the next line if the pattern space becomes empty. Many times I had to do 's/[^\n]*//'  just to mimic the "D" command but without starting the next cycle. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/10\.(45\.56\.84|81\.51\.92)/d' file
```

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -Fv -f <(echo $'10.45.56.84\n10.81.51.92') filename
```

Comment: Thanks for not having to escape everything!

Answer (score 0):

awk -F " " '{if($1 != "10.45.56.84") if($1 != "10.81.51.92" ) { print $0;}}' inputFile > OutputFile

**Explanation** : 
awk  : Awk is a scripting language used for manipulating data and generating reports.

" " :  its is used for delimiter. if data is separated by | then need to mention like "|"

{if($1 != "10.45.56.84") if($1 != "10.81.51.92" ) { print $0;}}' : pattern(Conditions) and print in outputFile

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!