# Shell - How to delete lines from text file with multiple patterns?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, sed

I saw this code below and it worked, but only for one pattern.

```
sed -i.bak '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

How can I use this statement but using multiple patterns? 
For example, if I wanted to delete lines with the word 'cat' or 'dog' inside.

I tried this but it did not work

```
sed -i.bak '/(cat|dog)/d' ./infile
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search multiple pattern in file and delete line if pattern matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760587/search-multiple-pattern-in-file-and-delete-line-if-pattern-matches)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special characters

```
\(cat\|dog\)
```

Comment: This matches `(cat` and `dog)`.

Comment: Yup, I changed it.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses at all (though this works now).

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple SED commands into single expression:

```
sed '/cat/d; /dog/d; /peanut/d' file
```

Or pass multiple expressions using `-e`:

```
sed -e '/cat/d' -e '/dog/d' -e '/peanut/d' file
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! But how can I ignore uppercase/lowercase? I tried      sed '/cat/id; /dog/id; /peanut/id' file , but this did not work

Comment: @RazliMahadi, Read https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unixlinux-sed-case-insensitive-search-replace-matching/

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
import re
f= open('file','r')
for line in f:
 data = line.replace("cat","").replace("dog","")
 if len(data) != 1:
  print data
```