# Excluding all lines from a file that match with a multi-value string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

This looks for a string `%exclude%` in a file `templist.m3u` and puts mismatching lines into file `files.m3u`.

```
findstr /irv "%exclude%" "%temp%\templist.m3u%" >%temp%\files.m3u
```

The problem is that the string `%exclude%` can sometimes have multiple values, separated by `,` like `s0,s1,s3` with a maximum of -- I don't know -- maybe five values. I need a list where all lines matching any of these values are removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760587/search-multiple-pattern-in-file-and-delete-line-if-pattern-matches

Comment: @G.C. I doubt it. This is `batch`.

Comment: Replace the `,` by _space_ to define multiple search strings for `findstr`...

Comment: I doubt it does what you say @Bricktop. You stated that it "looks for a string `%exclude%` in a file `templist.m3u`", however it appears to be looking for a string or strings matching the expanded value of the variable, `%exclude%` in a file named `templist.m3u%`! Also based upon your expected variable value content, you may wish to change `%exclude%` to `%exclude:,= %`

Comment: @Bricktop Let me guess and correct me if i'm wrong, you want just extract all links from the m3u file ?

Comment: @Hackoo, how did you make that determination from the question, my reading in this example is that they want a version with, seasons `2`, `4-9`, `20-29`, and seasons `40-99` etc.

Comment: @Compo I don't know if he means by s0,s1,s3 as seasons, but anyway, he should clarify by an example to understand more his aim !

Comment: The problem as I see it, is that they're trying to use a command, commands, or a batch file, as a find and replace tool, when there are hundreds of better, quicker and more user friendly ways of doing that. Hell, most basic third party text editors, would do a better job of it, not to mention the built-in WSH or PowerShell functionality, which use proper regular expressions.

Comment: @aschipfl solved the issue. Only changed to `%exclude:,= %` and it works beautifully.

Comment: _...and here was me thinking it was I_

Comment: Are you sure you want the search string(s) to be interpreted as regular expressions? If not, then you want `/ilv` instead of `/irv`. Otherwise something like `.` will match any character instead of a period, and countless other possible gotchas.